# How Do I know if a software has KDE or GNOME dependencies?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, kde, gtk, qt

I came to know that there are [Desktop Independent Apps and Desktop Dependent Apps.](https://www.fossmint.com/desktop-independent-apps-vs-desktop-dependent-apps-in-linux/)

In a Fedora forum thread [Gnome vs KDE applications](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?246098) there is this:

> keep in mind the distinction between 'KDE apps' and 'Qt apps', and
>   'GNOME apps' and 'GTK+ apps'. It's actually quite simple. GTK+ and Qt 
>   are the graphical toolkits (well, mostly; both have sprouted quite a
>   few functions beyond this area these days) associated with GNOME and
>   KDE respectively. An app which *only* uses resources provided by GTK+
>   is a GTK+ app but not a GNOME app; you don't need to have any bits of
>   GNOME proper installed to install or use it. Ditto for Qt and KDE -
>   you can write an app such that it *only* uses the Qt toolkit but none
>   of the KDE functions, and that's a Qt app but not a KDE app.
>
> Practically, any 'GNOME app' is also a 'GTK+ app' and any 'KDE app' is
>   also a 'Qt app', but not vice versa. Running a Qt app on GNOME or a
>   GTK+ app on KDE is unlikely to result in any missing functionality,
>   and will result in a lower increase in resource usage, than running a
>   KDE app on GNOME or a GNOME app on KDE. Running GTK+ apps on KDE is
>   particularly common, especially since all the Fedora config tools, and
>   PackageKit, are GTK+ apps.

It also stated that:

> some people prefer to install only apps from the desktop they run, to
>   make sure they don't accidentally use non-native apps and use extra
>   memory or miss functions and so on. It's really kind of a personal
>   preference thing, and depends how badly you rely on apps from 'the
>   other side'.

I am probably one of those people. So, I need to know if a software has specific KDE or GNOME desktop environment dependencies **before installing it**.

I found from [How are KDE Apps Able to Run under GNOME?](https://www.howtogeek.com/184667/how-are-kde-apps-able-to-run-under-gnome/) that a program written for GNOME will use `libgdk` and `libgtk`, and a KDE program will use `libQtCore` with `libQtGui`.

How can I easily know if a program has these dependencies before installing them?

Is there a better solution to know if a program has any specific DE dependencies?

Comment: You may think yourself to be one of those people, but *try* not caring about the difference for a week or two first. See if you can really detect a difference in memory or responsiveness. Most Ubuntu users have both sets of libs installed, and live happily.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I also think I am overthinking this. However, I at least need to know if a software has specific KDE or GNOME desktop environment dependencies before installing it. Whether I decide to go ahead with the installation regardless of the dependencies would be a different thing.

Comment: To find the direct dependencies of any package, simply use apt: `apt depends <package_name>`. You may need to go a couple levels down to discover the particular libs. This is a fairly basic, beginner-level use of apt, and well documented.

Comment: is there any command like `apt depends <package_name> libQtCore libQtGui libgdk libgtk`? So, that I can specifically know if it is dependent on these packages?

Comment: No. You must script it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small script that maybe useful:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter Package"
read Package

apt-cache depends --no-pre-depends --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances $Package | grep -E "(qt|gtk|kde)"
```

I called it *zzxx* and saved it to *~/bin* which is in my *$PATH*
and made it executable. If you don't have *~/bin* in your *$PATH*, you can use `$HOME/path/to/script/zzxx` (and make an alias for it).

Sample output:

```
$ zzxx
enter Package
chromium-browser
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
$ zzxx
enter Package
evince
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
$ zzxx
enter Package
firefox
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
$ zzxx
enter Package
lxappearance
  Depends: libgtk2.0-0
$ zzxx
enter Package
qterminal
qterminal
  Depends: libqt5core5a
  Depends: libqt5dbus5
  Depends: libqt5gui5
  Depends: libqt5widgets5
  Depends: libqt5x11extras5
  Depends: libqtermwidget5-0
$ zzxx
enter Package
vlc
  Depends: vlc-plugin-qt
$
```

Programs described as "Desktop Independent" in your first link such as *libreoffice* may come up empty when you run the script.

```
$ zzxx
enter Package
libreoffice
$
```

**Notes:**

- You need to enter the correct package name using the appropriate case (mostly lower case) and `apt search` in helpful for this purpose.
- The script will obviously work only for software available in the repositories you have enabled.
- I used `apt-cache depends` instead of `apt depends` to avoid a routine message: "WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts."
- The script isn't a substitute for looking at the entire output of, for example, `apt show firefox` which will provide a lot more information.
- The script may fail with "transitional packages".